# Script type="text/javascript" variable not catching PHP echoed JSON

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I'm working on a PHP web app that retrieves loads of data from a MYSQL database, then uses PHPs json_encode to convert the associative arrays into JSON.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json = <?php
    // get loads of data from MYSQL database, store in $array
    echo(json_encode($array));
    ?>;
</script>
```

This appeared to work fine before, but now when pressing F12 in chrome and checking the console, JavaScript throws an error as it doesn't recognize the opening < in the `<?php`.

I've found that if I remove the type="text/javascript" from the script tag, it reads it fine.

EDIT:

If I use the following, it works:

```
<script>
    var json = <?php
    // get loads of data from MYSQL database, store in $array
    echo(json_encode($array));
    ?>;
</script>
```

It seems that adding a type to the script tag prevents PHP from executing prior to it being sent to the client side device.

Why is this?

Comment: If the string `<?php` is present when the code makes it to the browser, then something has gone wrong on the **server**.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't know anything about PHP. If your PHP tags aren't being processed, then you have an issue on the server side.

Comment: Is it a .html-document or a .php-file?

Comment: It's definitely a PHP file - There are no errors with the PHP - it was showing an error when I accidentally tried to use $array = []; to declare an array (rather than $array = array();) - which I fixed, but it's still not working.

Comment: did you try to view the page source? instead of F12 to see what actually gets rendered.

Comment: It only throws an error if I use <script type="text/javascript"> rather than <script>

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the  tag can actually be used to run PHP code, if you use:

`<script language="php"> echo("hello"); </script>`

I assume that setting a type in the script tag makes it only evaluate a single language within the tags - leaving it without a type allows it to stay a multi-language script tag.

Source: http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/qt/mixed_scripting.htm

Therefore, using something like

```
<script>
var json = <?php
echo($var);
?>;
</script>
```

will evaluate both languages (obviously PHP server side), but setting a type or language in the script tag will prevent other languages / types within the tags from being evaluated.